# How to store all topics present in the kafka cluster to another topic using KSQL

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I'm new to KSQL. I want to store all topics names present in a kafka cluster to another topic using KSQL query.
`SHOW TOPICS;` from KSQL CLI gives me list of topics. I want to store all these topic information in another topic by creating a stream.
I will be polling this new topic (using a consumer) and whenever a new topic get created in the cluster, my consumer will receive a message.
I want a KSQL query to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't currently achieve what you want using ksqlDB. The `SHOW TOPICS` command is a system command, not a sql statement.  So the output of the query can't be piped into a stream.

ksqlDB allows you to process the data within the topics in the Kafka cluster. It doesn't (yet) allow you to process the metadata of the Kafka cluster, e.g. the list of topics, or consumer groups, etc.

It may be worth raising a feature request on GitHub: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/new/choose